# GCV to estimate ridge regression parameter

Tags: cross-validation, ridge-regression

One way to estimate the ridge regression parameter lambda is by generalised crossvalidation (GCV; http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~wahba/ftp1/oldie/golub.heath.wahba.pdf), as implemented in the `lm.ridge` function in R. I would be interested to know people's opinion on whether it is ok to use the same data for both GCV and the actual ridge regression with the chosen lambda, or there is a danger of overfitting, as in:

```
library(MASS)
a = data.frame(a=jitter(1:10), b=jitter(1:10), y=seq(10,100,10))
r=lm.ridge(y~a+b, a,lambda = seq(0,1,0.001)) 
select(r)
# modified HKB estimator is 0 
# modified L-W estimator is 0 
# smallest value of GCV  at 0.047 
r2 = lm.ridge(y~a+b, a,lambda = 0.047)
```

Or should I perform GCV on a subset of data and then fit the final ridge model to the remaining dataset?